# Deleting braces from array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am trying to delete "{" and "}" from array which looks like:

```
data = [{'Python'}, {'5'}, {'Golang'}, {'4'}, {'PHP'}, {'3'}]
```

Solutions like converting array/list to string and after that replacing symbols do not work as expected.

Could you help with it, please?

Im waiting output like:
['Python', '5', 'Golang', '4', 'PHP', '3']

Comment: What you have there is a list comprised of a number of sets. What output are you hoping to get?

Comment: How did the data end up in this format? It'd be better to fix the problem at the source: change the code that's spitting out the data to not have the unnecessary `{...}` sets, instead of patching it up afterwards.

Comment: Why do you have a list of sets all containing one item? If they all really contain one item in your real data, then you could just do `[item.pop() for item in data]`, which would turn your list of sets of strings into just a list of strings: `['Python', '5', 'Golang', '4', 'PHP', '3']`. But if you could avoid putting the sets into your list in the first place, and instead just put the strings directly in it, that would make more sense. I get the feeling that this is an "[XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: it happened after scraped data through bs4, I mean {...} format of list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This array looks to be a list of sets with a single element.
You can create a new list of strings:

```
data = [''.join(my_set) for my_set in data]
```

The output is:

```
['Python', '5', 'Golang', '4', 'PHP', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
new_data = []
for item in data:
   new_data.append(item.pop())
data = new_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[list(i)[0] for i in data]
```

Outputs:

```
['Python', '5', 'Golang', '4', 'PHP', '3']
```

Comment: There is no need to convert to a list in order to get a single element out of a set...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator:

```
>>> list(s.pop() for s in data)
['Python', '5', 'Golang', '4', 'PHP', '3']
```

Comment: Or just `[s.pop() for s in data]`... (4 bytes shorter :P)